# python: word segmentation based on dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

I am having a **dictionary** :

```
dict = ["as", "ass", "share", "rest"]
```

and a string **input** :

```
string = "xassharest"
```

And i want to show all possible words can made based on dictionary like this :

```
[('x', 'as', 's', 'h', 'a', 'rest'), ('x', 'as', 'share', 's', 't'), ('x', 'ass', 'h', 'a', 'rest')]
```

Actually i've tried it using all combinations of string (using library itertools) but it takes so long. Here is my code :

```
def getallpossiblewords(string):
    allwords = preprocessingcorpus("corpus.txt")
    temp = []
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        for j in range(1, len(string) + 1):
            if string[i:j] in allwords:
                temp += [string[i:j]]

    allposwords = sorted(temp, key=len, reverse=True)
    #print(allposwords)
    return allposwords

def wordseg(string):
    a = string
    b = getallpossiblewords(string)
    cuts = []
    allpos = []
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        cuts.extend(combinations(range(1,len(a)),i))
    for i in cuts:
        last = 0
        output = []
        for j in i:
            output.append(a[last:j])
            last = j
        output.append(a[last:])
        for x in range(len(output)):
            if output[x] in b:
                allpos += [output]
                #print(output)
    #print(allpos)

    fixallpos = list()
    for sublist in allpos:
        if sublist not in fixallpos:
            fixallpos.append(sublist)
```

I need the fastest algorithm to solve this problem, because the input of string may be even longer.

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. You should say if this is the case. You should also show what you have tried so far, and mention the exact problems you ran into. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you are calling a dictionary:  dict=["a","as","ass","share","rest"]  is NOT a dictionary in Python.  You need to do some research on the topic of your intended question, attempt to answer the question yourself, then come here for help

Comment: jdv : thank you for your suggestion, i've edit my post. btw can you help me maybe?
Dr t : that dictionary just for example, yeah i'm in research right now, i've solved this problem using CRF (machine learning based) but i need other algorithm (dictionary based). Maybe can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posted code merely defines two routines and stops without executing any active commands.

Comment: Why does your given solution not include ["a", "ssh", "a", "rest"] ?  Why *does* it include ["a","s","sha","rest"]: I don't see a reason to split "ssha", or not to sepearate the second "a".  One of us doesn't yet understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Prune. I'm sorry, i'm new here so please guide me. Btw i've change my exact problem. Is that clearly for you?

Comment: Now, "x" is not part of the dictionary, so such a word cannot be generated based on this dictionary.

Comment: yeah, "x" not in dictionary but there is word like "as" and "share" in dictionary, it can still give some possible segmentation as i write in example : ["x", "as", "share", "st"]. "x" and "st" not in dictionary.

Comment: Since neither `"hare"` nor `"st"` are in the "dictionary", I don't see how you consider `["x", "ass", "hare", "st"]` a valid result -- why isn't `["x", "ass", "har", "est"]` equally valid?  Or better yet, neither.

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://github.com/alvations/mini-segmenter

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a perfect recursive use of `str.partition()`.  Below is my example implementation that I won't claim solves every problem (since there are practically no test cases) but rather tries to do a selling job on this particular approach:

```
def segmented(string):

    segmentations = set()

    for word in words:
        before, match, after = string.partition(word)

        if not match:
            continue

        prefixes = segmented(before) or [before]
        suffixes = segmented(after) or [after]

        if prefixes and suffixes:
            for prefix in prefixes:
                for suffix in suffixes:
                    segmentations.add((*prefix, word, *suffix))
        elif prefixes:
            for prefix in prefixes:
                    segmentations.add((*prefix, word, *suffixes))
        elif suffixes:
            for suffix in suffixes:
                    segmentations.add((*prefixes, word, suffix))
        else:
            segmentations.add((*prefixes, word, *suffixes))

    return segmentations

words = ["as", "ass", "share", "rest"]

print(segmented("xassharest"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
{('x', 'as', 's', 'h', 'a', 'rest'), ('x', 'as', 'share', 's', 't'), ('x', 'ass', 'h', 'a', 'rest')}
%
```